# Javascript error 'has no method push'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting the error: `object 0 has no method 'push'`, and I can't figure out why.

I know that `sack[i]` is the object, `i` is 0 and `quantity_to_spawn` equals 1.

I think that node has an issue with pushing because sack is an array and `sack[i]` is actually an object.

```
for (i=0;i<rows[r].quantity_to_spawn;i++){
      more_drops = Math.random()
      sack[i]=new Array();
      for (;more_drops > .05;){
          more_drops = Math.random()
          rarity = Math.random()
          if (rarity <= .75&&typeof rows[r].common=="string"){//common drop 75%
             item=rows[r].common.split(",")
             sack[i].push(parseInt(item[parseInt(Math.random()*item.length)]))
                  ...
```

Comment: Are you declaring `sack` before the outer `for` loop as an array?

Comment: I'd be more comfortable if I saw a few `var` keywords in there...

Comment: Use semicolons, they should not be optional. Why does it seem everything is also global?

Comment: Also your random times length is going to give issues when Random returns one.

Comment: Add `var sack = [];` before the first `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you are missing to declare the variable `sack` as an array,

```
var sack = new Array();
```

or

```
var sack = [];
```

Otherwise it should work

Here is the [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwRrA/2/)

I made some experiment regard to this problem, found some interesting facts. Those are,

The problem is `sack` is already assigned something like `var sack = 'someValue';`. in **this case (assigned value string type)**, this resulting in `sack` to be a string array. Hence the assignment `sack[i]=new Array();` make no sense. `sack[0]` will be `s`. and try to push some value to this will throw the error `object 0 has no method 'push'`

**Another case(assigned value number type)**, assignment is like `var sack = 28892;`. In this case, the same array assignment making no sense. But if you try to push something to `sack[0]` it will throw `Cannot call method 'push' of undefined`, since `sack[0]` is `undefined`.

In both cases, after declaring `sack` to some value, the assignment not produced any error, though it is useless.

Additional information about array declaration,

[Javascript array declaration: new Array(), new Array(3), ['a', 'b', 'c'] create arrays that behave differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246406/javascript-array-declaration-new-array-new-array3-a-b-c-create)

Comment: This can't be the issue. If it was, there would be `sack is undefined` thrown just before the second `for` loop.

Comment: @Teemu no, what will happen if the variable defined as `var sack;`, obviously there would be no such error.

Comment: In that case the error would be `Can't set property 0, object is null or undefined` in line `sack[i]=new Array();`. There's no way to execute code past this line, if `sack` is not an array. OP's having this error: `object 0 has no method push`, this tells that object (=== `sack[0]`) exists, but there's not method called `push` in that object.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are doing here, but try this:

```
var sack = [];
for (var i=0;i<rows[r].quantity_to_spawn;i++) {
  var more_drops = Math.random();
  sack[i] = [];
  for (;more_drops > 0.05;) {
      more_drops = Math.random();
      var rarity = Math.random();
      if (rarity <= 0.75&&typeof rows[r].common==="string") {//common drop 75%
         var item = rows[r].common.split(",");
         sack[i].push(parseInt(item[parseInt(Math.random()*item.length,10)],10));
         ...
```

Comment: This can't be the issue. If it was, there would be `sack is undefined` thrown just before the second `for` loop.