# Date and Time Script

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm trying to produce a date and time script from JS beginners, I'm sure some of you have seen this before.

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong and am struggling to problem solve it as the log just spits out 'error'.

**Can anybody clear this up for me,** sticking to my general way of writing the script. Explanations would be great!

```
var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDay();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
var sec = date.getSeconds();

var weekdays = [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday];
var today = weekdays[day];

var amPm = amPmFunc;
function amPmFunc() {
    if(hour < 12) {
        amPm = AM;
    } else { 
        amPm = PM;
    }
}

console.log("Today is: " + today);
console.log("Current time is: " + hour + amPM + ":" + min + ":" + "sec");
```

Comment: Should Sunday etc be in quotes?

Comment: To start, all of the elements in your weekdays array need to be strings (surrounded by ").

Comment: Should `AM` & `PM` be in quotes too?

Comment: I think you should take a short course in JS to get familiar with arrays, strings, objects and formatting in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to enclose some strings with `''`. i.e. `Sunday` should be `'Sunday'`.

Also - remember - Javascript **is case sensetive**. So a variable called `amPm` will not be recognized as `amPM`.

Also, your function `amPmFunc` should return a value, rather than set a global variable's value. It's just neater this way. And when you do call it, call it with brackets: `var amPm = amPmFunc();`.

But other than that - Good job! ☻

See this fixed example:

```js
var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDay();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
var sec = date.getSeconds();

var weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var today = weekdays[day];

var amPm = amPmFunc();

function amPmFunc() {
    if(hour < 12) 
        return 'AM';
    else 
        return 'PM';
}

console.log("Today is: " + today);
console.log("Current time is: " + hour + amPm + ":" + min + ":" + "sec");
```

Comment: Bah these syntax errors are the bane of my life >.<  ...Thanks for the break down really helped.

Comment: Happy to help, and good luck with your learning. Ping me here if you have more questions. @11-

Answer (score 3):

**For why?**

1. **[`Array` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246406/javascript-array-declaration-new-array-new-array3-a-b-c-create)** was wrong .Missed the quotes to formatting  the string in array
2. Javascript is [**case sensitive**](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/case-sensitivity-in-javascript.asp) one.so don't forget case of the letter
3. For function  declare you could use `()` like `var amPm = amPmFunc()` .And add the [**return statement**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp) on `ampm` function otherwise its returning undefined .

> MY **suggestion** :For better you good study how to declare the [variable](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp) , function and
>   string  in js

```js
var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDay();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
var sec = date.getSeconds();

var weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var today = weekdays[day];

var amPm = amPmFunc()

function amPmFunc() {
  if (hour < 12) {
     amPm = 'AM';
  } else {
    amPm = 'PM';
  }
  return amPm
}

console.log("Today is: " + today);
console.log("Current time is: " + hour + amPm + ":" + min + ":" + "sec");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var weekdays = [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday];
```

They should be strings.

```
var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. All strings must be in "
2. name_of_function();  instead name_of_function
3. Functions must return somethings, yours amPmFunc() was not returning amPm

---

```
    var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDay();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
var sec = date.getSeconds();

var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var today = weekdays[day];


function amPmFunc() {
    if(hour < 12) {
        amPm = "AM";
    } else { 
        amPm = "PM";
    }

    return amPm;
}
var amPM = amPmFunc();
console.log("Today is: " + today);
console.log("Current time is: " + hour + amPM + ":" + min + ":" + "sec");
```

Comment: Perhaps single quotes are better - Saves on interpreting the string

Comment: Just added bug fix to hour function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
var sec = date.getSeconds();

var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var today = weekdays[day];

var amPm = '';
    if(hour < 12) {
        amPm = 'AM';
    } else if (hour > 12){ 
        hour = hour - 12;
        amPm = 'PM';
    } else {
        amPm = 'PM'
    }
console.log("Today is: " + today);
console.log("Current time is: " + hour + amPm + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
```