# Colon after an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

does anyone know what this syntax is in Javascript?

I got a function like so:

```
function myFunc(param) { 
  return {
     [var.prop]: param.func(args);
  };
}
```

That looks like a colon after an array. Would anyone know what that means in JS?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this your question? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246406/javascript-array-declaration-new-array-new-array3-a-b-c-create)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do square brackets around a property name in an object literal mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831262/what-do-square-brackets-around-a-property-name-in-an-object-literal-mean)

Comment: For future reference, if you have question about syntax, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript) is a good link to consult

Comment: Such semicolon in object literal is syntax error: `({a:1;})` → `SyntaxError: missing } after property list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal the object with key we know will be look like,

```js
function myFunc() {
  const newObj = {
    'key': 'value'
  }
  return newObj;
}

console.log(myFunc());
```

In the above you can able to see that the `'key'` act as a known string.

Suppose in your app if you get that string in dynamic format then you can add square bracket around like `[]` and can assign value of that property as a key to an object.

For eg.., You are getting the key from an object like,

```
const data = {
  prop:'dynamicKey'
};
```

And you need to assign the value of prop as key to an obj then you can use it like,

```
[data.prop]: 'value'
```

```js
const data = {
  prop:'dynamicKey'
};

function myFunc() {
  const newObj = {
    [data.prop]: 'value'
  }
  return newObj;
}

console.log(myFunc());
```